# No longer have Administrator permissions on my personal computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

A few months ago I lost my Administrator privileges on my own PC. I believe I encountered this issue when trying to change my account username and during it accidentally changed the account permissions.

[The account is neither listed as an Administrator nor a standard user account, instead a "HomeUsers" account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBIRY.png)

## So far I have tried the following to fix this issue:

- *Going to Family & Other Users to change the account permissions (the tab does not show up)*
- *Access administrator privileges through safe mode (asks for the built-in admin password)*
- *Boot the computer through a USB with using a Password Refixer (was unable to as I could not pay for the software)*
- *Fixing the issue through Local Group Policy Editor (local users and groups tab does not show up)*

I have also considered booting the computer through a USB with the windows installation media on it and use Shift + F10 to solve the problem from there.

***I am wondering if there is any free and safe way that I am able to regain my administrator permissions on my own PC. I have been working on trying to fix this for quite a while now but have been unable to find any success. Your help would be greatly appreciated on this issue.***

Answer (score 0):

Download "Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor" from the official website ([here](http://pogostick.net/%7Epnh/ntpasswd/)). It allows you to reset the password for the administrator account or to promote your working normal account to one with admin privileges.

Comment: I have a question regarding using this method. It states to "Install bootloader on the USB drive, from command prompt in windows (start the command line with "run as administrator" if possible)
X:syslinux.exe -ma X:". Is this a necessary step, and if so how would I be able to do this in command prompt ran as administrator if my PC does not have admin rights?

Comment: You will need access to another PC where you do have admin rights to do this or you will have to ask someone to create the usb stick for you.